# Commented code being hit while remote debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

During remote debugging in eclipse, the debugger is hitting commented codes and skipping actual codes. I tried cleaning and building the project, as suggested in the answer to another similar question on stackoverflow, but it didn't work.

Please suggest what is to be done to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this a remote debug? did you save your changes before cleaning and building? are you sure you are running the version you think you are running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happends because the code **deployed** on the machine you're debuging on is not the same as the source code you are using in your IDE to debug. If you rebuild and **redeploy** your application this is supposed to solve your issue

Comment: I'm sorry, this is dumb, but how do I deploy my code to tomcat?

Comment: Is tomcat on your machine ? or in a remote machine ?

Comment: I have 2 machines in a network. One has mysql and Android studio, the other has tomcat and eclipse. I'm having problems debugging my code in the machine with eclipse and tomcat.

Comment: So if I get it right eclipse and tomcat are on the same machine ! If so you can build your app, take your WAR(the file generated after the build) and put it under webapss folder of your tomcat this should get the work done.